# Is there a way to import __future__ in Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'd like to run a Python program on Colaboratory. It runs successfully using PyCharm, but it requires `__future__`.  When I try it on Colaboratory I get this error.

```
    from __future__ import annotations
                                      ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Any suggestions about how to import `__future__` on Colaboratory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__future__` exists. That particular `__future__` feature doesn't. Google Colaboratory is currently on Python 3.6, and `from __future__ import annotations` is 3.7.

If you need Python 3.7, you'll have to wait.

Comment: Disappointing, but thanks. Do you know why it is taking so long to upgrade to 3.7?

Comment: @RussAbbott: Lack of urgency, probably.